# Atom Snippets - Getting saved but not listed and doesn't work

Tags: atom-editor, code-snippets

My snippets.cson file :

```
'source.css':
 'Default':
  'prefix':'dcss'
  'body':"""
  *
  {
    padding : 0;
    margin : 0;
     $1
  }
"""
```

When I save this file, I get no error, but when I type "dcss" and hit tab. Nothing seems to appear.

I've read through this;

https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/1867

and implemented it as well it still doesn't seem to work

[image: The snippets.cson file]
[image: Snippet not listed]

I am running Atom in safe mode so that the init script doesn't interfere.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are two mistakes in your snippet:

1. Syntax scopes in Atom are prefixes with a dot, so your prefix should be `.source.css`
2. CSON is sensitive on indentation, so you need to make sure it's consistent (the closing `"""` aren't indented correctly).

Put together, your snippet should look like this:

```
'.source.css':
  'Default':
    'prefix': 'dcss'
    'body':"""
      *
      {
        padding : 0;
        margin : 0;
        $1
      }
    """
```

Comment: I forgot that I also fixed the indentation. I've updated my answer!

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: Did you copy & paste my snippet? Maybe restart Atom. Works fine for me!